# How to access transcluded child scope in nested AngularJS directives

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive `agreementDialog` that in turn uses the generic dialog directive `myapp-dialog-window-modal`:

```
angular.module('myapp.common.extra').directive('agreementDialog', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><myapp-dialog-window-modal window-title="Agreements" dialog-visible="agreementDialogVisible">'
                    + '<p>You need to accept the new terms.</p>'
                    + '<p><label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="variableInTranscludedChildScope"/>I accept the agreement</label></p>'
                    + '<p><button ng-click="submitAgreement(didAgree)">Submit</button></p>'
                + '</myapp-dialog-window-modal></div>',

        controller: function ($scope) {

            $scope.submitAgreement = function (didAgreeLocal) {
                console.log(`submitAgreement`, didAgreeLocal);
            };

            $scope.didAgree = false;
            $scope.agreementDialogVisible = true;

        }

    };
});
```

I need access to the variable `variableInTranscludedChildScope` mentioned in the code (the checkbox), but since it's *inside* the transcluded content, it has a separate scope (it's a child to `agreementDialog`’s scope and a sibling to `myapp-dialog-window-modal`’s scope). What's the best way of accessing it?

Comment: have you tried using bindings or even events?

Comment: @PanosK What do you mean by bindings? I'd like to avoid events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-model="smth.variableInTranscludedChildScope"

controller: function ($scope) {
  $scope.smth = {};

  // you can access $scope.smth.variableInTranscludedChildScope here
}
```